# Photoshop javascript - Removing a channel by text contained in the name

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript

I have a problem with the photoshop channels.
I'm trying to remove a channel if part of its name matches with "MaskFF".
So it could be "MaskFF", or "MaskFF_12345", or "12345 MaskFF".
But so far I haven't had any luck, everything I use gives me "Error 1302: No such element".
I also tried simple loops like this, to get an alert with the name of each channel:

```
var doc = activeDocument;
for(i=0; i<doc.channels.length; i++);{
    alert(doc.channels[i].name);
    }
```

but even that doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?
Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

Seems like there was a semicolon where it shouldn't have been.
Now the loop works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by myself:

```
    for (i = app.activeDocument.channels.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        if (app.activeDocument.channels[i].name.indexOf("MaskFF") !==-1) {
            app.activeDocument.channels[i].remove ();
        }
    }
```

or

```
    for (i = app.activeDocument.channels.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        if (/MaskFF/.test(app.activeDocument.channels[i])) {
            app.activeDocument.channels[i].remove ();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is data in the doc object?

Comment: Yes, there was data, but also a semicolon in the wrong place.